# running a php file without calling it

Tags: php

How can I run a php file without opening in browsers? Can I do that with php? or Should I use other languages?

i.e. sending a birthday mail to users otomaticly

i.e.2 send a ping every 5 hours etc

Comment: Set the cron job to execute that file with the desired schedule

Comment: @Teneff: that link doesn't even exist (and if it did, it'd be likely to be unrelated to the php core). please don't post random links without testing them.

Comment: > dig www.php-cli.com A # ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 48196  - and some further investigation shows that the domain used for the nameserver entries of php-cli.com is not registered...

Answer (score 4):

for automate your scripts you should use [cron](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use python for it.

However, PHP works perfectly fine for this purpose. It has the `cli` SAPI which is meant for commandline scripts (including cronjobs etc.).

Simply start your PHP file with the hashbang line pointing to the PHP interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'hello shell';
```

Answer (score 0):

CLI is command line interface. And from cron you can start your PHP scripts through command line.

Try this to start and you will understand what to do next:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Form you command line run something like
C:>c:\php\php.exe c:\path\to\your\script.php